# How to select students name born before a particular date in SQL Server

Tags: .net, sql-server

I am learning SQL Server and trying to get all the students born before a particular date, say born before March-1996.

```
select * 
from Test 
where MONTH(hire_date) <= 03 and YEAR(hire_date) < 1996
```

This is my query, but it is not returning the proper results. It is mainly checking the year ideally it should print all the students born before March-1996. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Where's your table structure? Oh, and are you really storing the birth_date in a column called hire_date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 100% guaranteed way (to the extent that's possible) to convert a string to a date in SQL Server is using YYYYMMDD, i.e. cast('19960301' as date).  Alternately, if the default COLLATION is used (or many others) then cast('1996-03-01' as date) works.  I prefer the latter.  Based on your example I think you're looking for something like this.

```
select * from Test where hire_date<=cast('1996-03-01' as date);
```